# If an event has probability $p$, how many trials until you see at least 1 occurrence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If an event $E$ has probability $p$, what's the expected number of trials until you see at least 1 occurrence of $E$?

I think it might be

$${1 \over p} * \log\left[{1 \over p}\right],$$

but I don't know if that's correct and I don't know how to prove it.

More generally, if $n+1$ independent events have probabilities $p_0, p_1, ..., p_n$ respectively, what's the expected number of trials until you see at least 1 occurrence of each?

Comment: Why do you have a log in there as well?

Comment: Hint: On first trial the success chance is $p$. If it were to fail,  on second trail it is $(1-p)p$. Repeating failure, then on third we get $(1 - p)^2p$. For $k$, generalised trials, we get $(1 - p)^kp$. Since, we want the expected number of trials, this would  follow: $E(X) = \sum{\text{ (current no. of trials) } \cdot \text{ (probability on current trail) }}$. What kind of a function do we get?

Answer (score 4):

Let $q=1-p$, the probability of failure on a single trial.

The probability that the first trial is needed is $1$.

The probability that a second trial is needed is $q$.

The probability that a third trial is needed is $q^2$.

The expected number of trials is the sum of the infinite geometric series
$$1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots=\frac1{1-q}=\frac1p.$$
**P.S.** What we're using here is *indicator variables* and the *linearity of expectation*. Namely, if $X$ is the number of trials needed, and $X_n$ is the indicator variable which takes the value $1$ is the $n^\text{th}$ trial is needed ane $0$ otherwise, then
$$X=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$$
and
$$E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n=1)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n-1}=\frac1{1-q}=\frac1p.$$

Comment: Your statement about the series is not correct. But by coincidence the answer is correct.

Comment: @M.Wind How is it incorrect? In problems like this it is tacitly assumed that the trials are independent, so $q^n$ is the correct probability that the first $n$ trials result in failure, and the correct expectation for the corresponding indicator variable. Also I assume that $p\gt0$ so that the geometric series converges.

Comment: @M.Wind The reasoning in this answer is correct. It follows from the general formula $E[X]=P(X\ge 1)+P(X\ge 2)+P(X\ge 3)+\dots$, valid when $X$ is a nonnegative integer random variable.

Comment: I disagree. The expected number of trials is given by $p + 2pq + 3pq^2 + 4pq^3 + ...$ and this can be evaluated to be $1/p$. If someone wants to use a different formula, this should be explained to the OP.

Comment: @M.Wind So by "incorrect" you mean "too terse"? You're saying I needed to include a line explaining that, if $X$ is the number of trials, and $X_n$ is the indicator variable which takes the value $1$ if the $n^\text{th}$ trial is needed and $0$ otherwise, then $X=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ whence $E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E(X_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n-1}$? If that's the problem, why didn't you just say so, instead of saying I got the right answer by "coincidence"?

Answer (score 3):

The number of independent trials until first success $X$ is geometrically distributed with parameter $p$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X = j) = (1-p)^{j-1} p$. From this, we compute $$\mathbb{E}[X] = p\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j(1-p)^{j-1} = p \frac{d}{dx} \left[\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x^{j} \right] \Bigg\vert_{x=1-p} = p \frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{x}{1-x} \right] \Bigg\vert_{x=1-p} = \frac{p}{(1-(1-p))^2} = \frac{1}{p}$$

Alternatively/equivalently, after noting $\mathbb{E}[X] < \infty$, we may condition on the outcome of the first trial. This yields the equation $$\mathbb{E}[X] = p \cdot \mathbb{E}[X \, | \, \text{first trial success}] + (1-p) \cdot \mathbb{E}[X \, | \, \text{first trial fail}] $$
Note that $$\mathbb{E}[X \, | \, \text{first trial success}] = 1$$ and $$\mathbb{E}[X \, | \, \text{first trial fail}] = \mathbb{E}[X] + 1$$ hence $\mathbb{E}[X] = p + (1-p)(\mathbb{E}[X] + 1) \implies \mathbb{E}[X] = 1/p$.

Comment: And correspondingly, to answer his second question, the expected number of trials until you see at least one occurrence of all the events is $\prod_i\frac{1}{p_i}$

Comment: @K.defaoite after you see an individual trial for which all events simultaneously occurred within that single trial... sure.  That is not the answer if we allow the events to occur across multiple trials.

Comment: If $\ p_i=\frac{1}{n+1}\ $ for all $\ i\ $ in the second question, then it becomes the standard [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem) for $\ n+1\ $ coupons. The expected time for the appearance of at least one of every coupon is known to be $\ (n+1)\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{j}\ $ in that case. As far as I'm aware, no simple expression for the waiting time is known when the coupons are not all equally likely.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera no.  The OP said that the $p_i$'s represent *independent events*, not that they represent mutually exclusive and exhaustive events.  In the standard coupon collectors problem, each time you draw a coupon... you draw *a coupon*.  Here, in the trials, in each trial we might have gotten one event to occur, multiple events to occur, or no events to occur.  This is not the same problem at all.

Comment: @JMoravitz My mistake. I inadvertently omitted omitted "and the events are mutually exclusive" from the conditions I specified in my opening statement. Thank you for pointing out the error. Since the probabilities I gave sum to $1$, then (under the conditions I intended to specify) the separate events will then also be exhaustive. The main point of my comment however, was that a (generalised) coupon collector's problem in which the coupons are not equally likely already seems to be a hard problem. As it's a special case of the OP's problem, the latter is likely to be even more difficult.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera they cannot simultaneously be mutually exclusive *and* independent.  That is an oxymoron.  If events are mutually exclusive (*and not empty*) then they are necessarily not independent and vice versa.  The OP specified they are to be independent.  They can not be mutually exclusive therefore and your point is moot.  "*As its a special case of the OP's problem*", no it isn't.

Comment: @JMoravitz Again, you're right. I was reading the OP's "independent" to be referring to the trials rather than the events at each trial. I'm still not completely sure that this was a misreading, but I should have taken the OP to mean exactly what he or she wrote, rather than what I thought he or she meant.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to JMoravitz for correcting my misunderstanding of the second problem. As stated, it's not as difficult as what I mistook it to be, although the expression for the expected number of trials doesn't appear to be reducible to anything that's very simple.

If $\ T_i\ $ is the first trial at which the $\ i ^\text{th}\ $ event occurs, then the first trial by which all of the events have occurred at least once is $\ \max(T_0,T_1,\dots,$$\,T_n)\ $.  Since the events are independent, so are $\ T_0,T_1,\dots,T_n\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
P\big(\max(T_0,T_1,\dots,T_n)\le t\big)&=P(T_0\le t,T_1\le t,\dots,T_n\le t)\\
&=\prod_{i=0}^nP(T_i\le t)\\
&=\prod_{i=0}^n\big(1-P(T_i>t)\big)\\
&=\prod_{i=0}^n\big(1-(1-p_i)^t\big)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
P\big(\max(T_0,T_2,\dots,T_n)\ge t\big)&=1-P\big(\max(T_0,T_2,\dots,T_n)< t\big)\\
&=1-P\big(\max(T_0,T_2,\dots,T_n)\le t-1\big)\\
&=1-\prod_{i=0}^n\big(1-(1-p_i)^{t-1}\big)\ .
\end{align}
Therefore, the expected number or trials until each event has occurred at least once is
\begin{align}
E\big(\max(T_0,T_2,\dots,T_n)\big)&=\sum_{t=1}^\infty P\big(\max(T_0,T_2,\dots,T_n)\ge t\big)\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^\infty\left(1-\prod_{i=0}^n\big(1-(1-p_i)^{t-1}\big)\right)\ .
\end{align}